Email Threading for Flow-Created Emails
I have a flow that runs on my Case object that sends out personalized emails when the Case enters different statuses.
As you can see I selected "Log Email On Send" and specified the related record as the triggering case. This email is sent out from an Org Wide Email address.

I see that the initial email is sending correctly, from our org-wide email, and it logs on the case.

But any subsequent replies to the email do NOT get logged on the case.
I looked into setting up "email threading" but I am not sure the simplest way to do that. I can turn on "Email To Case" but I am afraid that that looks like it opens a bag of worms and will start logging emails in other situations that are not intended. We only need it for this particular use case, replies on these cases.
I can't get a straight answer on if there is a simple way to do this so that the email replies auto-log on the case, without turning on Email-To-Case, or, if I do need it, how I can disable it from running in any other situation.
Does anyone know the simplest way to do this?
Thank you

Email threading is only supported OOTB with email-to-case.  If you don't want to enable email-to-case (which would be unusual, but OK), then you'll need to implement an Apex Email Service that inspects the incoming email for something that does the same thing as a Lightning Threading Token (LTT). For example, embedding the Case.Id in the outgoing email that you search the incoming email using a REGEX for to match

I guess I dont fully understand what flipping on "email to case" does. would it automatically create cases any time certain org-wide emails are emailed? Because there would never be a use case to create a new case. we would only want to append to existing ones.

Enabling E2C establishes a routing address of your choice (e.g. support@mycompany.com). All outbound emails from that Case include a threading token. Any inbound emails to that address create a Case unless they include the threading token, and if so, thread the inbound email to the Case rather than creating a new one.
